# Unable to delete single message from inbox (Android version 4.1.2)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to delete single message from inbox with their specific id. I picked individual message id from listview which consist of HashMap arraylist correctly now i want to delete message by this id. but i cant succeeded yet.

Delete function:

```
// delete inbox sms
    public boolean deleteInboxSms(String id, Context context) {
        context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }
```

kindly tell me is this correct uri statment or not?

Permisssions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Not duplicate. My android version is 4.1.2

Comment: Cool. Please specify that in your question.

Comment: @MikeM. please help me

Comment: getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/" + id), null, null);

Comment: not working @KanaiyaBhanushali

Comment: You sure the ID is correct?

Comment: Oh, wait. Remove `/inbox` from the `Uri`. That is, change it to just `Uri.parse("content://sms")`.

Comment: i toasted the id . the id is correct

Comment: i toasted the id . the id is correct

Comment: not working. can you please post correct full line @MikeM.

Comment: `context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms"), "_id = ?", new String[]{id});`

Comment: please ref this code http://pulse7.net/android/android-delete-sms-message-from-inbox-in-android/

Comment: @MikeM. you're great. its working, please post as answer.

Comment: It's cool. You can accept Sohail's, if you want, after he corrects his syntax (he's got a `)` in the wrong place). His way is slightly more appropriate anyway, because the way we have it is treating the ID as text. It's working, though, because of the way SQLite handles type conversions for comparisons. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Syntax

```
 context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"+id),null, null);
```

Comment: its your sms id no which you want to delete. in you case see updated answer.

Comment: you just have replace `_id` to `id` is your problem fixed.